# error trying to load exiftool

Tags: python, module, file-not-found, exiftool

I have installed exiftool (https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) and I am able to import the library, but I get the following error when trying to run the test data just to see if it works.

```
ERROR: test_get_metadata (__main__.TestExifTool)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site- 
packages\pyexiftool\test\test_exiftool.py", line 66, in test_get_metadata
with self.et:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\exiftool.py", line 191, in __enter__
self.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\exiftool.py", line 174, in start
stderr=devnull)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also did run the setup code that is in the exiftool folder and still no luck. I think it might be a library issue or path or the (*init*.py) file, but I've tried several ways and so I'm here to ask if anyone else has a solution or ideas for me to try and fix it.

I'm running Python 3.6.6 and have tried other versions.

(I can run exiftool in command line, but I have encoded BASE64 images that exiftool doesnt work in command line to fully decode.)

Comment: Where is exiftool located on your computer?  Is it in a directory that is part of the PATH env variable?

Comment: It's in the C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages of python, do I need also add the pyexiftool to the PATH env variable?

Comment: I also tried adding the actual exiftool.exe to the path in case I had missed the point that I actually still need the exiftool.exe application to run the python code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you StarGeek! The problem was that I didn't have the exiftool command tool (the separate application of exiftool) in the right PATH env variable. Once I added the application to the PATH env variables i got it to work. Also in the python exiftool code at line 70 it says that you have to have it in the path or direct it to the executable, that I had missed. Thanks again!